# Find the domain of analyticity of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Find the domain in $\mathbb{C}$ where the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 - 1}$ is analytic.

So far I've tried to take the derivative of $f$ and got $f'(z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2 - 1}}$ which is not defined in $\mathbb{C}$ at $z = \pm1$
However that is not the correct answer. The solutions say it's the whole interval from -1 to 1.

Comment: Did you try anything??

Comment: This is a multi-valued function, so I don't think the question is even correctly put.

Comment: Yes, I took the derivative and checked its domain. I got that it is not defined in $\mathbb{C}$ at the points 1 and -1. But the answer to it is not that. It's the whole interval from -1 to 1.

Comment: @avs I don't know what you mean. The OP is trying to determine where $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$. Are you saying that $f$ can not be analytic in any domain of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Pedro There are an infinite number of ways to cut the plane so that in the cut plane, $f$ is analytic.  One way is to adjoin $-1$ and $1$ with a straight line segment.  Another way is to cut the plane from $-1$ to $\infty$ and $1$ to $\infty$.  In fact, the branch cuts need not be straight lines.

Comment: No, I am saying that it is not a function until we choose one of the branches of the square root.

Comment: @avs But isn't that precisely the problem the OP is trying to ask?

Comment: Not sure what they are trying ot ask, but choosing branch is not equivalent to establishing analyticity at a point or in a set.

Comment: @JackyChong, see the comment above from Dr. MV.

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that this question is a misrepresentation of a possibly better question, or else a bad question in an unfortunate context... namely, as most of us can easily see, except at $z=\pm 1$, *locally* there are two holomorphic square roots of $z^2-1$.

A possibly operational point is that much traditional curriculum does not even attempt to talk about *local* holomorphic functions, a.k.a. "germs", or anything else operationally equivalent, despite clear use of such ideas 150+ years ago, in Riemann's work and others'.

So, for example, a benighted "correct answer" to the question would likely involve choosing a *global* "domain", that is, a maximal open on which a well-defined section (!) exists. But, of course, there is no single such thing. And the question fails to ask for this.

Still, yes, it can be interesting to ask for two different things: first, to ask for the bad points, which have no neighborhood on which there can be a holomorphic square root; second, to ask for an *example* of a maximal (and not too hard to describe) set on which there is a global section...

Comment: :) Sometimes things are a wee bit complicated... :)

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, but you got me thinking that I shouldn't have left out a part of the question. I'm going to translate it exactly word by word: Determine in the complex plane the analyticity domain of the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 - 1}$, where the square root is defined as $\sqrt{|w|}$ * e^(i$\theta$\2), with $\theta$ in the interval from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Comment: @Pedro, ah, yes, those are some (perhaps disputably sensible but) necessary details to have there be an answer... :)

Comment: @ paulgarret so is it possible for you to try to explain why the answer says -1 to 1 rather than what i initially thought?

Comment: @Pedro, it is an anticlimactic thing to note that on the complex plane with that interval removed (or any squiggly line from -1 to +1) there is a well-defined square root... One of several reasons you might have not anticipated this is the unfortunate curricular inertia that seems to tell you that there's a "unique/canonical" region on which some potentially multiple-valued function is sensible. That suggestion is grossly false. There are canonical local functions, and there are various more-global choices, but no canonical "best". Too bad, but that's the truth.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean when you say that the function is "sensible"? Same by canonical. Sorry for all these stupid questions I just want to try to make some sense of this. I'll ask my teacher tomorrow anyway